# Confusion about id of list element

Tags: python

I have written the code of python , which is mentioned below

```
def fun(l):
    l[0]=20
    print(id(l[0]))

no=10
list_=[10,11]
fun(list_)
print(id(list_[0]))
```

From the above code i get output as

```
10911008
10911008
```

Now, my question is how can the `id(l[0])` and `id(list_[0])` be same because when `fun(l)` modifies `l[0]`, the reference count of memory location having value 10 is more than 1

Comment: You answered your question yourself: "`fun(l)` _modifies_ `l[0]`".

Comment: @ForceBru yes but l[0] is local to fun(l) then why the id(list_[0]) is getting changed, as l[0] and list_[0] are in different scopes

Comment: Right, they're different _names_ that refer to the same _object_.